# Displaying Column Headers Once in Output Report

Tags: powershell, powercli

I'm writing a script to audit the disk partition types in my company's virtual environment using PowerCLI. I've got this code so far:

```
$report = @()

$VMs = (Get-VM).where{$_.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn' -and $_.Guest.OSFullName -match 'Windows'}

foreach ($VM in $VMs){
    $vmName = $VM.Name
    $output = Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText @'
      Get-Disk | 
        select @{ l="ComputerName"; e={ $env:COMPUTERNAME } },
               Number, 
               @{ name='Size'; expr={[int]($_.Size/1GB)} },
               PartitionStyle
'@ -VM $vmName -GuestUser $Username -GuestPassword $Password

    $output.ScriptOutput #printing each for testing
    $report += $output.ScriptOutput
}
$report | FT -AutoSize
```

This will produce an output that looks like this:

| ComputerName | Number | Size | PartitionStyle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VMNAME1 | 0 | 100 | MBR |
| VMNAME1 | 1 | 20 | GPT |
| VMNAME1 | 2 | 20 | MBR |

| ComputerName | Number | Size | PartitionStyle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VMNAME2 | 0 | 100 | MBR |
| VMNAME2 | 1 | 20 | GPT |

The issue I'm facing is that the output report has the column headers repeated for each VM. How can I fix this to only have the column headers displayed one time, like this:

| ComputerName | Number | Size | PartitionStyle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VMNAME1 | 0 | 100 | MBR |
| VMNAME1 | 1 | 20 | GPT |
| VMNAME1 | 2 | 20 | MBR |
| VMNAME2 | 0 | 100 | MBR |
| VMNAME2 | 1 | 20 | GPT |

Any ideas for how I can do this? I'm new to powershell so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Remove or comment out the line `$output.ScriptOutput #printing each for testing`. Also concatenating to an array with `+-` is costly.

Comment: @Theo removing that had no effect on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the output of ScriptOutput is string, you'd have to parse it yourself. Instead I recommend transforming it into a format suitable to be passed around as text, such as CSV.

```
$VMs = (Get-VM).where{$_.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn' -and $_.Guest.OSFullName -match 'Windows'}

$report = foreach ($VM in $VMs){
    $vmName = $VM.name
    $output = Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText @'
      Get-Disk | 
        select @{ l="ComputerName"; e={ $env:COMPUTERNAME } },
               Number, 
               @{ name='Size'; expr={[int]($_.Size/1GB)} },
               PartitionStyle | ConvertTo-Csv
'@ -VM $vmName -GuestUser $Username -GuestPassword $Password

    $output.ScriptOutput | ConvertFrom-Csv
}

$report | FT -AutoSize
```

Also, as Theo commented, `+=` can be very expensive and is almost always unnecessary. As shown here you can simply collect the output of the foreach directly into the variable.

**Edit**

Since any extra output such as errors gets capture along with the data you want, it can cause the extra blank lines you mentioned. One way I was able to overcome this was to check for the existence of a column header and then strip away any junk before.

```
$VMs = (Get-VM).where{$_.PowerState -eq 'PoweredOn' -and $_.Guest.OSFullName -match 'Windows'}

$report = foreach ($VM in $VMs){
    $output = Invoke-VMScript -ScriptText @'
        Get-Disk | Foreach-Object{
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                ComputerName   = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                Number         = $_.number
                Size           = [int]($_.size/1GB)
                PartitionStyle = $_.PartitionStyle
            }
        } | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

'@ -VM $vm.Name -GuestUser $Username -GuestPassword $Password

    if($output.ScriptOutput -match 'PartitionStyle')
    {
        $output.ScriptOutput -replace '(?s)^.+(?="Com)' | ConvertFrom-Csv
    }
}

$report | FT -AutoSize
```

Comment: This produces a nearly blank output except for some permission denied errors when trying to connect to some VMs - see [here](https://gist.github.com/VTSquirrel/8853e69d42cb46483f08dc40966f4495)

Comment: That’s a separate issue

Comment: Yeah I know, not really concerned about those errors at the moment, though. Will investigate each of them separately. Just not sure why the output would be blank to begin with...

Comment: If there is any other output including errors included that all goes into the output. I'd run each VM one by one and see what errors you're getting.

Comment: Check my edit. Some extra steps should help you get the desired output. If you have the choice to switch to Invoke-Command, for your own sake please do. Sending a script as a string and all output being returned as a string is what powershell was made to save us from.